# how do I merge two dicts , but keep the same structure?

Tags: python, merge

I am trying to merge two dicts without knowing the size of each one , but I want to keep the array structure however I am getting the folowing output ,, but however I need to make it  `{'lucky_color': ['red', 'Sunday'], 'lucky_num': [1,2,3]}`

output

```
{'lucky_color': ['red', 'Sunday'], 'lucky_num': [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]}
```

merge dicts

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
  common_keys = set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys())
  dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}

  for k in common_keys:
    dict3[k] = [dict1[k], dict3[k]]

  return dict3
d1 = {'lucky_color':'red', 'lucky_num': [1,2]}
d2 = {'lucky_color':'Sunday', 'lucky_num': [1,2,3]}
d3 = mergeDict(d1, d2)
print(d3)
```

Comment: Is a list merge supposed to remove all duplicates? What if `lucky_num` was `[1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: no problem . I Just need unique values, however I want to keep as single array not 2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output structure is actually different from the input.  Each key now has a list for its value instead of the original type.

Ggiven this your merge function needs to build lists from the value so it can't simply concatenate the keys.

In order to not make a list of lists for the values that are already lists, you'll need to have an exception on the data type in your merge logic.

```
def mergeDicts(*dicts):
    merged = dict()
    for d in dicts:
        for k,v in d.items():
            if not isinstance(v,list): v = [v]                    
            merged[k] = list(set(merged.get(k,[]) + v))
    return merged

d1 = {'lucky_color':'red', 'lucky_num': [1,2]}
d2 = {'lucky_color':'Sunday', 'lucky_num': [1,2,3]}

d3 = mergeDicts(d1, d2)
print(d3) # {'lucky_color': ['red', 'Sunday'], 'lucky_num': [1, 2, 3]}
```

*Note your example seems to imply that you want your resulting lists to behave like sets so that required a few more manipulations*

Comment: sure , it's okay , but however I want to keep the unique values from `lucky_num` than having a 2d array

Answer (score 0):

Assume there only have **string** or **list like** type of object in your dicts value and same key corresponding to same type of value:

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
    common_keys = set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys())
    dict3 = {}
    for k in common_keys:
        if isinstance(dict1[k], str):
            combined_list = [dict1[k], dict2[k]]
        else:
            list_1 = list(dict1[k])
            list_2 = list(dict2[k])
            set_1 = set(list_1)
            set_2 = set(list_2)
            
            list_2_items_not_in_list_1 = list(set_2 - set_1)
            
            combined_list = list_1 + list_2_items_not_in_list_1
        dict3[k] = combined_list

    return dict3

d1 = {'lucky_color':'red', 'lucky_num': [1,2]}
d2 = {'lucky_color':'Sunday', 'lucky_num': [1,2,3]}
d3 = mergeDict(d1, d2)
print(d3)
```

Outputs:

```
{'lucky_color': ['red', 'Sunday'], 'lucky_num': [1, 2, 3]}
```